# grails tomcat 7 deployment

Tags: oracle, tomcat, grails, driver, classnotfoundexception

So I have a grails 2.0.4 application that works exactly the way I want. I created the war file and deployed it to Tomcat 7. I'm getting an error saying that the application can't find the jar I'm using to connect to oracle (ojdbc6.jar). The jar is listed under mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib. WHY can't it be found?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The jar file should be in the toplevel `lib` directory of your project (or specified as a dependency in a repository), not `webapp/WEB-INF/lib`.  Is the jar file actually inside the warfile?  You can test this by opening the war as a zip file, or by running `jar tf target/mywebapp*.war` and looking for `ojdbc6.jar`.  If it is, it should get deployed and you should see it in `tomcat7/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib`.
2. The default environment for `grails war` is `production` instead of `development`.  Make sure you've got the `production` data source configured correctly in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`

Comment: Ok I'm a little confused. The top level of my project doesn't have a lib directory. It has WEB-INF/lib. Where should I put the jar?

Comment: The jar file is there. I can see it in WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar

Comment: When you run `grails create-app xyz`, a directory called `xyz/lib` gets created.  That's where you should put the jar.  When you run `grails war`, the file gets placed in `WEB-INF/lib` inside the war.  When tomcat extracts the war, it ends up in `WEB-INF/lib` inside tomcat's `webapps`.  That final place is where it needs to end up.

Comment: Yes, the jar is there. Why can't the application find/use it?

Comment: Hmm, strange.  Does `ojdbc6.jar` appear in the `Bundle-ClassPath` attribute in the war file `MANIFEST.MF`?